# Install opencv AWS instance

Tags: opencv, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using a reserved instance in AWS ec2 and am trying to install opencv on it. When I tried,

```
    sudo apt-get build-essential
```

I got the following output

```
   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
   Get:1 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libasan0 amd64 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 [63.0 kB]
   Get:2 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libatomic1 amd64 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 [8,626 B]
   Get:3 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libgmp10 amd64 2:5.1.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [218 kB]
   Get:4 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libisl10 amd64 0.12.2-1 [419 kB]
   Get:5 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libcloog-isl4 amd64 0.18.2-1 [57.5 kB]
   Get:6 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libgomp1 amd64 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 [23.2 kB]
   Get:7 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libitm1 amd64 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 [28.5 kB]
   Get:8 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libmpfr4 amd64 3.1.2-1 [203 kB]
   Get:9 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libquadmath0 amd64 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 [126 kB]
   Get:10 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libtsan0 amd64 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 [94.7 kB]
   Get:11 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libmpc3 amd64 1.0.1-1ubuntu1 [38.4 kB]
   Get:12 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main binutils amd64 2.24-5ubuntu3.1 [2,076 kB]
   Get:13 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libc-dev-bin amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 [68.9 kB]

   Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.13.0-48.80
   404  Not Found [IP: 54.185.154.163 80]

   Get:14 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libc6-dev amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 [1,910 kB]
   Get:15 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main cpp-4.8 amd64 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 [4,439 kB]
   Get:16 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main cpp amd64 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 [27.5 kB]
   Get:17 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libgcc-4.8-dev amd64 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 [1,688 kB]

   Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.13.0-48.80
   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

   Get:18 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main gcc-4.8 amd64 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 [5,012 kB]
   Get:19 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main gcc amd64 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 [5,098 B]
   Get:20 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libstdc++-4.8-dev amd64 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 [1,050 kB]
   Get:21 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main g++-4.8 amd64 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 [7,038 kB]
   Get:22 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main g++ amd64 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 [1,490 B]
   Get:23 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main make amd64 3.81-8.2ubuntu3 [119 kB]

   Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libdpkg-perl all 1.17.5ubuntu5.3
   404  Not Found [IP: 54.185.154.163 80]

   Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main libdpkg-perl all 1.17.5ubuntu5.3
   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
   Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main dpkg-dev all 1.17.5ubuntu5.3
   404  Not Found [IP: 54.185.154.163 80]

   Get:24 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main build-essential amd64 11.6ubuntu6 [4,838 B]
   Get:25 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libfakeroot amd64 1.20-3ubuntu2 [25.4 kB]
   Get:26 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main fakeroot amd64 1.20-3ubuntu2 [55.0 kB]
   Get:27 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libalgorithm-diff-perl all 1.19.02-3 [50.0 kB]
   Get:28 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl amd64 0.04-2build4 [12.6 kB]
   Get:29 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libalgorithm-merge-perl all 0.08-2 [12.7 kB]
   Get:30 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libfile-fcntllock-perl amd64 0.14-2build1 [15.9 kB]
   Get:31 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main manpages-dev all 3.54-1ubuntu1 [1,820 kB]

   Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main dpkg-dev all 1.17.5ubuntu5.3
   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

   Fetched 26.7 MB in 1s (14.6 MB/s)
   E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_3.13.0-48.80_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

   E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/libdpkg-perl_1.17.5ubuntu5.3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

   E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg-dev_1.17.5ubuntu5.3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

   E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I take it that I have to make some changes to the file containing information regarding the servers and sources? Can you please tell me how to fix this?

When I tried

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

it worked. I take it that it worked, cuz it was empty?

**UPDATE**

I tried the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382257/unable-to-do-apt-get-upgrade-or-update-not-found) and thisis the updated output I get.

```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package.
  This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
  is only available from another source

  E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate
```

Any pointers from here please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

first follow the solution from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382257/unable-to-do-apt-get-upgrade-or-update-not-found)

and then run

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

Clean!